# Uploading images to a specific folder on disk using JSP

Tags: java, jsp

hey guys please refer to this post.....[Uploading Images Using JSP/Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996080/how-to-store-image-on-disk-using-servelets-but-path-in-database-oracle)

my question is if we upload a same image multiple times, how will be the image stored...? for example, if one uploads an image **ABC.jpg**, and the other user also uploads the image with the same name, how will the system accept it, coz normally in any OS when we try to add a file with the same name, it either asks to **"REPLACE"** OR **"RENAME"** the file.

so how to use this concept...??
thanks

Comment: How you decide to store the image on the server side is completely up to you.

Comment: but thats what my question is...i want the files to be uploaded on a particular folder on the disk, but as i said, there are chances that the user uploads the file with same name(though the files may be different)....so any solution to that???

Comment: What the file is named on the server should not be important. If you need to retain the file name somewhere, keep it as metadata somewhere else (like a database).

Comment: @NilsH....well i said, i have to store the image on the disk bt only the filename on the database...so can it be done??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my projects, I always change the name of file uploaded, and add to it the time of upload in millis. This being, there is really a very little chance that two users upload the same file at the very same moment.

Comment: well i areally agree to that...bt can u just guide me like with a snippet of code(or any other example on stackoverflow)...well i just need a reference, on how to implement in a JSP/servlet page...
Thanks...